# timestamp when a specific field gets updated

Tags: mysql, sql

database

```
+------------------------+
|animals|names|timestamp |
+------------------------+
|lion   |simba|12-02-2017|
|------------------------|
|hippo  |hip  |13-02-2017|
+------------------------+
```

I basically want the timestamp column just to get updated if the field "names" for example gets updated/changes, not when animals gets updates/changes. (timestamp obviously gets the current timestamp)
ty for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If Animals field is Your main field (id) then :

```
CREATE TRIGGER timestamptrigger AFTER UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if NEW.names <=> OLD.names THEN
 update table set timestamp = CURDATE() where animals = New.animals
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER`,and in trigger just check `'OLD.names !=NEW.names'` if then make entry of `SYSDATE()` in update query.
Hope this will help.

Comment: While it's a small thing, `NOW` should be used instead. [`SYSDATE` is the date when the `SYSDATE` function is executed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) whereas `NOW` will return when when the statement or function its in was executed. Multiple `SYSDATE` calls in a single function or statement will result in different dates, whereas `NOW` will not. For example, `select sysdate(), sleep(1), sysdate();` vs `select now(), sleep(1), now();`.